# Understanding memory allocation behaviour for arrays using malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I have this simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 

int main(){ 

int (*array)[2] = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    printf("%p\n",array[0]); //0x13c606700
    printf("%p\n",array[0]+1); //0x13c606704
    printf("%p", array[1]); //0x13c606708
}
```

I'm using malloc to allocate memory for an integer array of 2 elements. This returns a pointer for this said array. However, I don't understand why `array[0]+1` and `array[1]` are yielding different addresses. `array[0]+1` prints the address at `array[0]` + 4 which is expected since an integer is of size 4 bytes. But this is not the same for `array[1]`. Why is this happening? Wouldn't intuition suggest that using malloc on a fixed-size array would enable the programmer to refer to the memory allocated using array notation (i.e array[i])?

Comment: Your declaration is almost certainly not what you want.  You have declared a pointer to an array of two int.  This is normally used for a two-dimensional array.  If you just want a dynamically allocated array of two `int`, the declaration should be `int *array`.  You *can* use what you have for a one-dimensional array, but it's unusual, and your references would need to look like `(*array)[i]` which isn't what you're doing.

Comment: An "integer array of 2 elements" is `int *array` (to be allocated) or `int array[2]`. For the first you need `int *array = malloc(sizeof *array * 2);` but then the data at `array[0]` and `array[1]` is indeterminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array[0]` is an `int[2]`. When passed to the function it decays into a pointer to the first element, an `int`, which is 4 bytes on your system.

`array[0] + 1` adds the `sizeof(int)` to the pointer.

`array[1]` is the next `int[2]` (out of bounds). That's the `sizeof(int)` times two.

Comment: If I may ask you (and apologise for my lack of knowledge). By using (*array)[2], did I allocate memory for 2 x 1d arrays of sizeof(int)*2 ? Meaning 2 arrays of 8 bytes?

Comment: @Nizar No, you only allocated space for two `int`s, so that's one `int[2]`.